# Where is the SignalR v2 Javascript API doc?

Tags: javascript, signalr

The closest I was able to get to an authoritative API doc was [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/%40aspnet/signalr/?view=signalr-js-latest), which is for ASP.NET Core. I'd love to see definitive properties for $.connection.hub (according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client) it has a transport property, an id property, and some event handlers), among other things.

Comment: you can search more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/

Comment: @HienNguyen I did a scan of the table of contents and couldn't find a classic API doc (the kind with a list of classes/types and their properties)